# FFMPEG amix audio to video with some audio in parts

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I'm using amix to blend some audio and video with

```
ffmpeg -i living.mp4 -i emotive.mp3 -filter_complex \
"[0:a]volume=1.0[a0];[1:a]volume=0.6[a1]; [a0][a1]amix=inputs=2[a]"\
-map 0:v -map "[a]" -c:v copy -c:a aac -shortest -strict -2 outputaMix.mp4
```

This works, however only for the part of the video that already has sound, in the part that is silent the music is not added in.  The music track is longer than the video.

How do I make the music play for the whole length of the video?

Comment: Need to see full console output. But my guess is you to pad in missing samples in the video's audio: `[0:a]aresample=async=1,volume=1.0[a0]`

Comment: That works.. and it as an answer and I'll mark it correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is your audio stream isn't continuous and only has packets corresponding to content. Pad in the missing samples in the video's audio: `[0:a]aresample=async=1,volume=1.0[a0]`